# Custom in-memory application bus as placeholder for Azure Service Bus

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, nservicebus, esb, azureservicebus

We have an application that I would characterize as complex.
The application is POS terminal software that initially will run only on one computer, but later should be easily scalable to many computers with central (possibly cloud) storage: many client terminals, application server with WCF services, database server.

In an MVC 4 application, we wanted to
**A)** keep the controlllers in the application light weight by moving the (business) logic from the controllers to services. That has been blogged and written about in books numerous times and seems a "right" way to decouple things.

Step **B)** would be to remove the coupling between the controllers and the services by introducing an (in-memory) application bus. I say in-memory because we don't need (want) an ESB right now.

So a controller would never call a service directly. Instead:

For instance, in `LineItemController.cs`:

```
ILineItemDetailService _service;
....
public void CreateLineItemDetail( DetailInfo d )
{
    _service.CreateLineItemDetail( d );
}
```

...would become something like:

```
IBus bus;
...
public void CreateLineItemDetail( DetailInfo d )
{
    _bus.Send( new LineItemDetailMessage( d ) );
}
```

A handler for this type of `LineItemDetailMessage` will receive the object and in turn call the `LineItemDetailService`. And so forth.

Our **requirements are speed and realiability** (duh!), as there can be a lot of data (>1000 messages per minute) being sent over the bus to the services, and eventually to the database.

My quesiton is, since we don't want to use Azure or cloud services right now, is it easy to **replace such a custom application bus** later on with **Azure** SB or **NSerivceBus**?

Or do you suggest "biting the bullet" and **do it right away**, use NServiceBus?

What **performance hit** are we looking at here if we are using a bus (loosely coupled) isntead of calling the service directly (tight coupling)?

Has anyone done this before and what is **your experience with the application bus pattern**?

So is writing a custom "bus" as a "placeholder" for future move to Azure even **feasable**?

Comment: Sounds to be what you're talking about is simply a queue abstraction.  Something that you can program to that can have different implementations.  OOD basics.  Likely a good idea (e.g. a facade) even if you don't need to switch things out later. One implementation could simply be `Queue<T>` or `ConcurrentQueue<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NServiceBus provides exactly the kind of IBus abstraction you're talking about. It also has a separate plugin model for transports so you can run it locally purely in-memory if you want, as well as on top of MSMQ, RabbitMQ, SQL Server, and on top of cloud services like Azure Service Bus and Amazon SQS/SNS as well.

Let me repeat that - you can use Azure Service Bus under NServiceBus with just some minor changes in configuration/initialization code.

Here's the docs on that: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/azure/

You won't have much of a performance hit by introducing NServiceBus. Even when running on fully durable and transactional infrastructure, you can get up to several thousand messages per second - well above the target you set.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Can NServiceBus account for the server side being offline (computer is down, internet is down) and somehow "cache" outgoing MSMQ messages until the server is back online? In other words, can we avoid having a local storage (database) in addition to having one on the central backoffice server? Are there docs on particular.net that describe this scenario? Thank you!

Comment: The way that NServiceBus sets up MSMQ, the answer is yes - messages are buffered locally if the server is offline.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to start with ServiceBus Server right away (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282144.aspx) - you can install this on the same windows box where you have everything else running.

One thing that I love about Windows Service Bus is the symmetry between Azure Service Bus (Cloud) and Service Bus Server (OnPremise). Install ServiceBus Server and design and code for it and test the Performance requirements with it and then if you decide to Scale out and move to Azure Service Bus (on Cloud) - Simply change the Namespace connection string and you are there (also need to get the latest Service Bus Service SDK Nuget and rebuild - you will see zero build issues - as it is fully backward compatible).

Going with an Abstraction is definitely a very good idea and is adequate for a Proof of Concept - but NOT if you really want to see / sort out functionality issues or decide on performance (latency and through put) numbers and obviously will need huge re-design and code churn - as each system (Bus) will have its own different form of offering - ex: scale numbers per queue etc.

Thanks!
Sree

Comment: Thank you Sree for this excellent answer. The only drawback is that it is for Windows Server, which the terminals are not going to run (Windows8). When using the ServiceBus, can the code be kept as simple as the code I used above in the MVC controllers? E.g. have an IBus implementation as an abstraction to the whole ServiceBus mechanism? Thank you!

Comment: My Pleasure John! Service bus can be installed on a Windows8 terminal as well (client OS) + Sql Express - extremely easy to install - this is only officially supported as a developer environment - not as a production server. I believe the code can be abstracted out to IBus implementation - but it will be a bit of work though.